# How to disable the python console

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygame

I'm doing a game with pygame, and I found really annoying that the console appears as it's doing nothing, so I tried to look for a way to disable/remove it but I found nothing.

I hope someone knows how to disable it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also want to export it to .exe and despite using multiple freezing modules none removed the console

Comment: Use `pythonw` Not `python`

Answer (score 0):

I find [Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) will do this as long as you use `console = [{script:"yourprogram.py"}]` instead of `windows = [{'script': "yourprogram.py"}]` in the setup script.

[Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) also has some command line options to do this, but I forgot what they are off the top of my head.

Could you post a concise version of your code which still exhibits the problem?